# Add character or special character in NString?

Tags: iphone

I have an NSString *string=@"606" and I want to add a ":" colon after two digits.
The output should look like this: `6:06`
It this is possible?

Help would be appropriated.
Thank you very much.

Comment: That colon is only after one digit. Please clarify your question and provide all possible examples.

Comment: @Evan Let me Clear by an example : NSString *string = @"606"; and need only String back after adding the colon in this "String" eg. "6:06". I hope this will clear.Thank you ..

Comment: Do you have an `NSDate` object from which you generated the string `606`? If you do, it is easier to use the same `NSDate` to generate `6:06`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the column between the hours and the minutes like this:

```
NSString *string = @"606";
NSString *result = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(string.length-2, 0) withString:@":"];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

This will give the following results

```
@"606"  =>  @"6:06"
@"1200" =>  @"12:00"
@"1406" =>  @"14:30"
```

Note: This will only work if the string has 3 or 4 characters, but this is the case according to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Because you do not have two separate objects for hours and minutes, use:

```
NSString *newTimeString, *hour, *minute;
NSUInteger length = [timeString length];
if (length == 3)
{
    hour = [timeString substringToIndex:1];
    minute = [timeString substringFromIndex:2];
}
else
{
    hour = [timeString substringToIndex:2];
    minute = [timeString substringFromIndex:3];
}
newTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", hour, minute];
```

I used a long version to illustrate the concept. Basically, use the length of the original string (`timeString`) to extract the time components and combine them with a colon.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be 2 digits no matter what? Otherwise you could build your custom string from parameters.

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", hours, minutes];
```

*UPDATE*

If you just need to add a colon after 1 char, you can do it this way. Although I would suggest finding a safer method as this could be inaccurate if you have a double digit hour.

```
NSString *hour = [NSString substringToIndex:1]; // double check the index
NSString *min = [NSString substringFromIndex:1]; // double check the index
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", hour, min];
```

Hopefully this will help.

Comment: but i have only a one string which contains 606 after calculating time.So is there any way because it can't help.